# WinError 87 Trying to install Kivy

Tags: python, cmd, kivy

Working on Windows

I'm using these instructions:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist

On step 3. Install kivy:

```
python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

I receive this error in CMD:

```
ERROR: Error [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

It's not the first time that I am encountering this error. I have never been able to solve it.

Comment: what is your python version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ran the command `kivy_venv\Scripts\activate` on the command line as the error could be due to the virtual environment not being initialized correctly. Optionally, You can do `pip install Kivy`, which will install the package for global use. Check out the package on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/).

Comment: I tried pip install Kivy, it completes successfully, but then when I try to import anything from Kivy it says that there is no module named Kivy.

Comment: @eyllanesc I use 3.7 at the moment

Comment: You have to make sure you import certain components from the Kivy package. Additionally, **make sure you are not using any virtual environment** when using Kivy when you installed it globally.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following first and then check whether the env is getting activated or not.

Open command prompt and execute the following:- type the extension of activate i.e bat. Don't end without extension

```
kivy_venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

After this run:-

```
PathofVenv\scripts\pip.exe install kivy
```